# would like help understanding javascript throttle function

Tags: javascript

A user on Stack Overflow posted a question related to overriding a native JS function. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282739/should-i-worry-when-overriding-function-tostring-in-javascript) and this is the code:

```
function throttle(fn, time) {
  var handle;

  var execute = function() {
    handle = null;
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  var throttled = function() {
    if(!handle) {
      handle = setTimeout(execute.bind(this), time);
    }
  };

  throttled.toString = function() {
    return fn.toString() + "\n// throttled to " + time + "ms";
  };

  return throttled;
}

var makeAjax = throttle(function(callback) {
  $.getJSON("/path", callback);
}, 500);
```

I have a pretty good handle (I think) on JavaScript, but there are some areas that remain very grey to me. I would like to know what is happening in this code?

I don't really understand what `bind` and `apply` are doing, or what the end result of this all would be. I've looked up `bind` and `apply` on Mozilla's JS documentation, but the "official" definition has done little to help me understand what they are doing in this context.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it quite hard to read as well, context juggling code is in general hard to read, and therefore error-prone.

`this` in JavaScript often refer to the parent of the function, that is, when a function is stored as the field of an object like:

```
function fun(){
    return this
}
obj = {f:fun}
```

Calling `obj.f()` will return `obj`, simply calling `fun()` however will return the `window` element as the function is not called as a member, so the value of `this` depend on context. When making a wrapper like the one you show the context for `this` will invariably change, the `bind` and `apply` methods are made for dealing with situations like that. `fun.bind(cont)` will make a version of `fun` where `this` is always `cont`. `fun.apply(cont,args)` will run `fun` with `this` set to `cont` and the values in the array `args` as parameters.

The code in question demonstrate how convoluted these things get by failing to pass the given arguments to the function. The real parameters are passed to `throttled`, but the `arguments` array that is used come from `execute`, it is empty.

Using the `bind` function is unnecessary, `this` could just as well be stored in a simple variable.

Here is a fixed, and in my opinion easier to read, version, along with code that demonstrate the functionality:

```
function throttle(fn, time) {
    var handle;
    function throttled() {
        var args;
        var context;
        if(!handle) {
            args = arguments;
            context = this;
            handle = setTimeout(execute, time);
        }

        function execute() {
            handle = null;
            fn.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    throttled.toString = function() {
        return fn.toString() + "\n// throttled to " + time + "ms";
    };

    return throttled;
}

obj = {
    toString:function(){
        return "obj's toString";
    }
    ,f:throttle(function(input){
        console.log(input+", "+this);
    },1000)
}
obj.f("input string 1")
obj.f("input string 2")
obj.f("input string 3")
obj.f("input string 4")
```

Comment: You're explanation of `bind` and `apply` completely makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple really - the handle of a setTimeout call is used as a guard against multiple execution.

The **throttled variable** contains a function that is also the return value - `makeAjax` will contain that function. When it is executed, it will either

1. Cause the `execute` function to be called after a delay, if handle has been cleared / not already set
2. Return immediately otherwise.

This makes the name of the function apparent - it throttles the execution of the input function to after a certain time, and no more than once concurrently.

It uses bind to set the `this` context of the function stored in the *execute variable*.

The **execute variable** is a function wrapping the calling of the input function with the clearing of the handle, so that whenever the function stored in `execute` is called it allows further executions of the function. The function uses apply to execute the function with a specific context and arguments.

I hope that clears something up - I found it hard to put into words at all, and I'm not sure I managed it in a clear and concise way.